# How to create a Swift object in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsobject

If you define a swift class like this

```
@objc class Cat {

}
```

In swift you can just do

```
var c = Cat()
```

But how do you make a `Cat` instance in Objective-C ?

Subclassing `NSObject` works because you can then "alloc-init" but can we achieve this without subclassing an Objective-C class?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_77) article will help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most direct way is to subclass `Cat` from `NSObject`. If you can't do that, you will need to make a class method or a function that returns a `Cat`.

```
@objc class Cat {
    class func create() -> Cat {
        return Cat()
    }
}
func CreateCat() -> Cat {
    return Cat()
}


Cat *cat = [Cat create];
Cat *cat = CreateCat();
```

Answer (score 1):

In modern objective-c you can call functions like they were properties:

Swift:

```
class func create() -> Cat {
    return Cat()
}
```

Obj-c:

```
Cat *cat = Cat.create;
```

Comment: While it is possible to call class methods this way due to how the compiler is implemented, it is generally bad form to do so. Dot notation is explicitly for accessing properties in ObjC. See "Dot Syntax Is a Concise Alternative to Accessor Method Calls" https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW5 "Dot syntax is purely a convenient wrapper around accessor method calls."

Answer (score 0):

You can declare `+alloc` in a dummy category (don't need to implement it):

```
@interface Cat (Alloc)
+ (instancetype)alloc;
@end
```

and then you can use regular alloc-init on it:

```
Cat *cat = [[Cat alloc] init];
```

all without needing to change the Swift code.