# Why am I getting warnings when the swift mixed project runs successfully?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I'm working on swift and objective-c mixed project. I rewrited a Class called JSTManager.h into Manager.swift. Then, I deleted JSTManager.h and JSTManager.m. Manager.swift is used in both swift and objective c files. The project compile and runs successfully, but Xcode shows warnings after succeeding successfully. The warnings are like,
code: `[Manager sharedInstance]`
warning: `Unknown receiver 'SoundManager'; did you mean 'NSUndoManager'?`
warning: `No known class method for selector 'sharedInstance'`

How can I remove these warnings?

Manager.swift is like

```
class Manager: NSObject {

    var player: AVPlayer?
    static let sharedInstance = Manager()

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code of Manager class

Comment: @NiravD  thanks for comment. I added a sample code.

Comment: What is `SoundManager` here? Have you imported related file of it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a Swift object in Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29949127/how-to-create-a-swift-object-in-objective-c)

Comment: @NiravD sorry for confusion. I mistyped. SoundManager is the one that i use in the real project, which should be Manager here. I updated the code snip

Comment: And now I don't get warnings. it's strange. Time fixed?

Comment: I think you meant to write UndoManager and not SoundManager. And if you're using Swift 3, sharedInstances should be just shared.

Answer (score -1):

Use like

```
class Manager: NSObject {

        var player: AVPlayer?
        static let sharedInstance = Manager()

        override init() {
            super.init()
        }
    }
```

Comment: i can not find a difference to the original code. can you explain it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41888036/why-am-i-getting-warnings-when-the-swift-mixed-project-runs-successfully#comment70959698_41888036