# Initialize swift nsobject via objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have this pod created in swift, it has this sample model

```
@objc public final class SomeModel: NSObject {
  var id: Int
  var someIdAgain: Int
  var name: String

  public init(id: Int, someIdAgain: Int, name: String) {
    self.id = id
    self.someIdAgain = someIdAgain
    self.name = name
  }
}
```

How can I initialize it with the arguments in objective c? ex in swift

```
SomeModel(id: 7, someIdAgain: 2, name: "John")
```

Comment: I think this is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29949127/how-to-create-a-swift-object-in-objective-c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a Swift object in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29949127/how-to-create-a-swift-object-in-objective-c)

Comment: Kinda the same but the difference is I need to pass the arguments, so how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Add `@objc` to your initializer to be able to use

```
[[SomeModel alloc] initWithId:42 someIdAgain:42 name:@"foo"];
```

Comment: I did this but I'm getting this error ```No visible interface @interface for `SomeModel` declares the selector `id:someIdAgain:name:````

Comment: That's weird. If the initializer is not visible to ObjC, the error message _should_ be `No visible @interface for 'SomeModel' declares the selector 'initWithId:someIdAgain:name:'` (at least, that's what I'm getting in Xcode 11). Make doubly sure you've changed the class to read `@objc public init(...)`.

Comment: I did a workaround for now, created a type method `initSomeModel(id: Int, someIdAgain: Int, name: String)` then inside of it I initialize the same class via the same arguments passed.